# Why does Django ORM allow me to omit parameters for NOT NULL fields when creating an object?

Tags: python, django, postgresql, django-models

Stupid question time.  I seem to be able to create an object for a Django model even though I omit a column that was defined as NOT NULL and I don't understand why.  Here's my model:

```
class Movie(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=256)
    length_minutes = models.IntegerField()
    rating = models.CharField(max_length=2)

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'movies'
```

When I run `python manage.py` sql I see:

```
BEGIN;
CREATE TABLE "movies" (
  "id" serial NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY,
  "name" varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  "length_minutes" integer NOT NULL,
  "rating" varchar(2) NOT NULL
);
COMMIT;
```

Also, if I run the command `\d movies` from the `psql`, I can see that all columns are designated `NOT NULL`.

But here's what I don't understand.  When I run the Python shell, I can issue the following command and a new row with an empty 'name' column will be created:

```
Movie.objects.create(length_minutes=120, rating='PG')
```

However, if I issue (what I believe to be) the equivalent SQL command:

```
INSERT INTO movies(length_minutes, rating) VALUES(120, 'PG');
```

... I get the error I would expect: "ERROR: null value... violates not-null constraint."

Why does Django's ORM allow me to create an object that lacks a parameter for a `NOT NULL` CharField column?  Does it assume that I'm using model validators?  If so, it seems to be a pretty dumb and trusting ORM.

I'm using Python 2.7.1, Django 1.4, and PostgreSQL 9.1.4.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: When you run the Django command `Movie.objects.create(rating='PG')`, what SQL is produced? Enable SQL logging in Django, or `log_statement = 'all'` in `postgresql.conf` then check the PostgreSQL logs. Show the statement that Django generates here. Personally I wonder if Django is not flushing the queries to the database, so the error isn't produced *yet*.

Comment: OK.  Here's what the logging showed: INSERT INTO "movies" ("name", "rating") VALUES ('', 'PG') RETURNING "movies"."id"; args=('', 'PG'). So it's inserting a blank if I leave out the 'name' parameter.

Comment: As I indicated above, I was executing the "Movie.objects.create..." command from the Python shell.  I just now confirmed that if I run it from a Django view, I get the same result... a new object is created in the movies table.  Again, I would have expected some type of SQL exception.  Wouldn't Postgres tell Django, "Hey, you're trying to insert a row without a value for a field that's NOT NULL. You should throw an exception on my behalf?"

Comment: You should look at Field.null and Field.blank.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After a great deal of online research and experimentation, what I've found indicates that the behavior I described above is normal Django behavior.  Apparently, Django doesn't validate models by default.  Furthermore, the default value for a CharField is the empty string.  In order to ensure that Django raises the expected IntegrityError if I omit a CharField parameter designated NOT NULL, I needed to add "default=None" to the signature declaration:

```
name = models.CharField(max_length=256, default=None)
```

Can I get credit for answering my own question?

Comment: You just saved me so much research. I was prepared for yet another rabbit hole. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

The empty string `''` is not `NULL`, it is the empty string. `''` is a perfectly valid non-null value. If `''` isn't an acceptable value to your application, add a `CHECK` constraint like:

```
ALTER TABLE movies
ADD CONSTRAINT movie_name_length 
CHECK (length(name) > 0);
```

It looks like Django, or your application, is assuming that when you don't specify a name you want an empty name `''`, not `NULL`. See [the Django documentation for `Field.null`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/), which isn't what I'd call ... clear ... but seems to suggest that *no value* is treated as `''` by default.

Comment: But I did show my model definition at the very top of this post.  According to the Django docs, unless I specify otherwise in my model (which I didn't), all fields are not null by default. The ORM is allowing me to execute a command which, if I wrote it in SQL, would trigger an error.  It's allowing me to totally omit a column that is  designated as not null which strikes as rather odd.

Comment: @RobertF. Ugh, sorry. Reading fail. Edited. As for `NOT NULL` - I agree that Django's behaviour is odd, it shouldn't be assuming the empty string when it isn't supplied with a value. It looks like it's purely a Django-internal thing, though, not related to PostgreSQL.

Comment: @RobertF. The Django docs suggest that this is expected behaviour, though the explanation is ... unclear. See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/ . As best I can guess, it's trying to say that "no value" is treated as `''` for text fields.

Comment: Just for fun, I added an additional field, "length_minutes = models.IntegerField()", to the model shown at the top.  If I do "Movie.objects.create(...)" and omit a parameter for this field, Python throws the IntegrityError I would expect. Python/Django is only allowing me to omit NOT NULL parameters for CharFields.

Comment: Still investigating this problem. I added "blank=False" to the CharField model signature for name and rating fields on the outside chance that the Django 1.4 documentation was incorrect in stating that this is the default. Unfortunately, the ORM still allows me to create new Movie objects even when I omit the name and rating parameters entirely.  My SQL log shows that the ORM generates this: INSERT INTO  "movie" ("name", "length", "rating") VALUES ('', 100, '') RETURNING "movie"."id"; args=('', 100, '')