# Datetime fields. How to add validation end_date is higher than start_date with DJANGO in python model class?

Tags: python, django, datetime, model, comparison

Can someone help me with this?
I try to add a validation like the following:

> start_date < end_date

These variables are datetime type. I hope someone already did this validation.

```
date_start = models.DateTimeField(
    verbose_name=_("start date")
)
date_end = models.DateTimeField(
    blank=True, null=True, verbose_name=_("end date")
)
```

Comment: You could do the validation when you create your object instead of inside the model. If you want to validate it inside the model you can override clean, take a look at this question : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945339/is-this-the-way-to-validate-django-model-fields

Comment: What would be the result if `date_end` value is **`None`** ?