# Django model field with a regex validator not working

Tags: django, regex, django-models

The below model has a regex validator, however, when creating new objects (with standard model instantiation and *model*.objects.create() ), there is no error message given when creating an object that violates the validator. It allows the object to be saved.

Below is the code for the model:

```
class Area(models.Model):
    area = models.CharField(max_length=6, validators=[RegexValidator(
        regex='^[A-Z]{1,2}[0-9][A-Z0-9]?$',
        message='Area is not in correct format',
        code='invalid_area'
    )])
```

Any advise would be much appreciated.

Comment: What is your expected output?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Model data is validated by the DjangoForm before it's inserted into a model instance. But there is no validation checks in model.save method. So you can trigger validation for you model like this

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.full_clean()
        super(YourModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Here more detailed answer to your question [Is this the way to validate Django model fields?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12945339/is-this-the-way-to-validate-django-model-fields)